# Error when running glxgears but xclock and xeyes work from Linux server with XForwarding on local OSX machine

Tags: linux, macos, xquartz, x-forwarded-for

I am trying to run glxgears or glxinfo from a server and I am receiving the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  25
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

My server is a Linux server and my local machine is OS X. However, I have tried running the same thing on a Linux machine and I am receiving the same error. I can run xeyes and xclock on the server and see the window pop up locally. If I saw nothing then I would think XForwading wasn't working at all, but since xeyes and xclock work then I am not sure what is going on.

What could be causing the *`BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)`* error?

Comment: The same problem happens to me too. I don't quite understand why it is downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this issue I downgraded Xquartz from 2.7.11 to 2.7.8. For some reason the newer version of Xquartz doesnt work...